# Different Jenkins version in jenkins-io and jenkins-ci.org

Tags: jenkins

https://jenkins.io/download/ show 2.138 as the LTS version today.
https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/ show 2.8 versions.

I couldn't the reason find why jenkins.io LTS shows a lower version whereas a higher version of jenkins war file is already available. Can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the LTS version is `2.138.1` and the weekly version is `2.141`. And `2.8` is actually smaller than `2.xxx`.

So there is neither a mismatch nor anything confusing here?

From the site itself:

> Long-term Support (LTS)
>
> LTS (Long-Term Support) releases **are chosen every 12 weeks** from the
>   stream of regular releases as the stable release for that time period.
>
> Weekly
>
> **A new release is produced weekly** to deliver bug fixes and features to
>   users and plugin developers.

Comment: Both LTS and weekly release are at 2.1xx. How come 2.8 is a smaller one?
If 2.8 version is released that should be available in the official Jenkins Download page right?

Comment: You have to strip the major version, so you're left with the subversion. And then it's just a simple comparision: 8 < 138